# How to use interface and generic same time in Function

Tags: typescript

how to use generic in a function which implement interface

in the example code how do I achieve a interface or type,which extract generality in ‘xFunc’ and ‘yFunc’，and which I can use ‘wantFunc’ to implement it to apply wantFunc like xFunc and myFunc

can I use 'wantFunc' to implements ITFunc without appoint generic T util it apply?

```
interface IFunc {
  (arg : any): string
}
interface ITFunc<T> {
  (arg : T): string
}
const myFuc: IFunc = (a) => a + 'my'
myFuc(null)
const stringFunc:ITFunc<string> = (arg) => arg + 'a'
const numberFunc:ITFunc<number> = (arg) => arg + 'b'
const xFunc = <T>(arg: T) => arg + 'x'
const yFunc = <T>(arg: T) => arg + 'y'
const wantFunc:ITFunc<T> = <T>(arg: T) => arg + 'want' // mistake
stringFunc('sss')
numberFunc(123)
xFunc<string>('ss')
yFunc<number>(123)
wantFunc<string>('ds') // how to do
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no syntactic way to express the idea: "I want this value to have multiple generic types". However, Typescript is structurally typed, which means you don't have to *say* that something has a given type for it to have that type; it simply has that type if it satisfies the corresponding interface. So this is one of the rare situations where you can fix your problem by *removing* type annotations.

```
const wantFunc = <T>(arg: T) => arg + 'want';
```

Then we can call it as

```
wantFunc<string>("A");
wantFunc<number>(99);
```

And, just to confirm, it is still a `ITFunc<T>` (for appropriate `T`), since we can assign it to a variable of the appropriate (monomorphic) type.

```
let wantFuncN: ITFunc<number> = wantFunc;
let wantFuncS: ITFunc<string> = wantFunc;
```

Comment: [Relevant GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17574) suggesting introduction of generic values